# I'm learning redux from the documentation and I'm trying to add new post after adding the usersSlice and I'm getting an error reading new post added

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to add a new post. Initially, the code was working fine but after adding the usersSlice and associating a user with a post, I have an error **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'substring')** from PostList.js. Below is the code somebody please assist.

*postsSlice.js*

```
import { createSlice, nanoid } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = [
  { id: "1", title: "First Post!", content: "Hello!" },
  { id: "2", title: "Second Post", content: "More text" }
];
const postsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "posts",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    postAdded(state, action) {
      state.push(action.payload);
    },
    prepare(title, content, userId) {
      return {
        payload: {
          id: nanoid(),
          title,
          content,
          user: userId
        }
      };
    },
    postUpdated(state, action) {
      const { id, title, content } = action.payload;
      const existingPost = state.find((post) => post.id === id);
      if (existingPost) {
        existingPost.title = title;
        existingPost.content = content;
      }
    }
  }
});

export const { postAdded, postUpdated } = postsSlice.actions;
export default postsSlice.reducer;
```

*usersSlice.js*

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = [
  { id: "0", name: "Tianna Jenkins" },
  { id: "1", name: "Kevin Grant" },
  { id: "2", name: "Madison Price" }
];

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "users",
  initialState,
  reducers: {}
});

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

*store.js*

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import postsReducer from "../features/posts/postsSlice";
import usersReducer from "../features/users/usersSlice";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    posts: postsReducer,
    users: usersReducer
  }
});

export default store;
```

*AddPostForm.js*

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { postAdded } from "./postsSlice";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

export const AddPostForm = () => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [content, setContent] = useState("");
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState("");

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const users = useSelector((state) => state.users);

  const onTitleChanged = (e) => setTitle(e.target.value);
  const onContentChanged = (e) => setContent(e.target.value);
  const onAuthorChanged = (e) => setUserId(e.target.value);


  const onSavePostClicked = () => {
    if (title && content) {
      dispatch(postAdded(title, content, userId));
      setTitle("");
      setContent("");
    }
  };

  
  const canSave = Boolean(title) && Boolean(content) && Boolean(userId);
  const userOptions = users.map((user) => (
    <option key={user.id} value={user.id}>
      {user.name}
    </option>
  ))

  return (
    <section>
      <h2>Add New Post</h2>
      <form>
        <label htmlFor="postTitle">Post title</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="postTitle"
          name="postTitle"
          value={title}
          onChange={onTitleChanged}
        />
        <label htmlFor="postAuthor">Author:</label>
        <select id="postAuthor" value={userId} onChange={onAuthorChanged}>
          <option value=""></option>
          {userOptions}
        </select>
        <label htmlFor="postContent">Content:</label>
        <textarea
          id="postContent"
          name="postContent"
          value={content}
          onChange={onContentChanged}
        />
        <button type="button" onClick={onSavePostClicked} disabled={!canSave}>
          Save Post
        </button>
      </form>
    </section>
  );
};
```

*PostsList.js*

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { PostAuthor } from "./PostAuthor";

export const PostsList = () => {
  const posts = useSelector((state) => state.posts);

  const renderedPosts = posts.map((post) => (
    <article className="post-exerpt" key={post.id}>
      <h3>{post.title}</h3>
      <p className="post-content">{post.content.substring(0, 100)}</p>
      <PostAuthor userId={post.user} />
      <Link to={`/posts/${post.id}`} className="button muted-button">
        View Post
      </Link>
    </article>
  ));

  return (
    <section className="posts-list">
      <h2>Posts</h2>
      {renderedPosts}
    </section>
  );
};
```

*PostAuthor.js*

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

export const PostAuthor = ({ userId }) => {
  const author = useSelector((state) =>
    state.users.find((user) => user.id === userId)
  );

  return <span>by: {author ? author.name : "Unknown author"}</span>;
};
```

*SinglePostPage.js*

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { PostAuthor } from "./PostAuthor";

export const SinglePostPage = ({ match }) => {
  const { postId } = match.params;
  const post = useSelector((state) =>
    state.posts.find((post) => post.id === postId)
  );

  if (!post) {
    return (
      <section>
        <h2>Post not found!</h2>
      </section>
    );
  }

  return (
    <section>
      <article className="post">
        <h2>{post.title}</h2>
        <PostAuthor userId={post.user} />
        <p className="post-content">{post.content}</p>
        <Link to={`/editPost/${post.id}`} className="button">
          Edit Post
        </Link>
      </article>
    </section>
  );
};
```

Comment: if you have installed redux dev tools, check if the `posts` have the data as you expect it to be

Comment: I've tried changing the onSavePostClicked method, it adds the post but does not add the user.  Here is [the link to the code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-night-iv59xi) I'm using. I've also left a comment where I've tried changing. Thanks in advance

Comment: I would highly recommend to pay concentration on cross checking the code, it should have been easily caught by yourself .... the code is already in place just a couple of cross checks

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

couple of things you are doing wrong

- dispatching the data, you don't have to pass an object, in `AddPostForm.js` just do as below (check e.g. from docs)

  `dispatch(postAdded(title, content, userId));`
- The way reducers added are wrong it should be as below (check docs)

```js
   reducers: {
    postAdded: {
      reducer(state, action) {
        state.push(action.payload);
      },
      prepare(title, content, userId) {
        return {
          payload: {
            id: nanoid(),
            title,
            content,
            user: userId
          }
        };
      }
    },....}
```

Adding [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-blackburn-epidpl?file=/src/features/posts/postsSlice.js:285-598) too, please fork and check